# Using modules with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend

I recently started using Webpack for frontend and came across the issue with modules.
For example, I have two modules, one uses another (to be specific its [angular-bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/angular-bootstrap-slider) and [bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider)). `angular-bootstrap-slider` was failing to initialize due the fact that `Slider` function was undefined.
 Now I understand that I can either export `Slider` globally (which I did with jquery and angular libs) or import `Slider` in angular-bootstrap-slider (I picked that).
 I don't like both options, because global exports is one of the things I wanted to avoid using webpack and importing something in library means changing it's code.
So am I missing something or maybe there is some best practice to deal with dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [shimming modules](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html).

This allows you to declare that `Slider` is in fact to be imported from the module `bootstrap-slider`:

```
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
    'Slider': 'bootstrap-slider'  
  })
]
```

Comment: Isn't it going to be global?

Comment: No, it's compiled into a `require()` call

Comment: So everywhere in a library call to `new Slider` compiles to require()? But what if I have two libraries with `Slider` constructor?

Comment: It's the Webpack `require()`, only one copy of the required module will be included. By the way, Node also caches modules so multiple `require()` calls for are never a problem.

Comment: I mean that I can have two different libraries with same function's name.

Comment: Oh, that wouldn't have worked previously, with globals, though. If one of those usages is in your code, you could just change the name, like `import SliderDirective from 'angular-bootstrap-slider'` (`var SliderDirective = require('angular-bootstrap-slider')` if ES5)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `imports-loader`: https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader

> imports loader for webpack
>
> Can be used to inject variables into the scope of a module. This is
>   especially useful if third-party modules are relying on global
>   variables like $ or this being the window object.

Comment: Seems nice, I will definitely try this

Comment: This is also a good solution but still requires editing the library's source, no?

Comment: As far as I understand, this loader adds `require` call to the target's source.